# how do I perform an if/else statement on a $_GET['id'] using php

Tags: php, mysql

so this is what I've got going on,

url is http://localhost/profile.php?id=255

then this

```
<? php

$profileID = $_GET['id'];

// -> this line represents my mysql query.

?>
```

and now when the code runs it will return errors and what not because the $profileID variable (that is now assigned "userID" 255) that the query searches the database for does not exist.

My question now is how do I perform a check on this $profileID variable to prevent the running of said mysql script and instead display an error to the user saying that the profile does not exist.

Comment: Do you want to check if  the mysql row exist or not , right?

Comment: There is no way to display this message without quering the database table. Unless you create a php array that has the profile ids as keys and the details of each user as values which of course is not the best way to do  it.

Comment: yes, I would like to check to see if it exists before anything else on the page runs, as the code stands, anyone can simply type any number as the id and the rest of the page runs.

Comment: i'm still trying to understand what you really mean...but if you want only an authorized user to see the page only....create a login system and check whether the user is logged on and actually has the id of 255 you are looking for before displaying anything aside from that you'll have to run the database query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you perform the query and then try to fetch the row, it will return `false` if the query didn't match anything. You can then test this with `if`. Here's what it looks like using PDO:

```
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM profiles WHERE id = :id");
$stmt->execute(array(':id' => $profileID));
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if ($row) {
    // process the results
} else {
    // Report that user doesn't exist
}
```

Comment: this helped, thank you very much. I never knew that the query would return a true/false, learn something new everyday. :)

Comment: Haven't you ever written a loop like `while ($row = $stmt->fetch())` to read all the results of a query? Don't you see that that's using `$row == false` to tell when it has reached the end?